# Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}: GitHub Actions

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, azure-sql-database

I am working on a **Spring Boot** project. For production environment, I am using **SQL Server** AND **Azure App Service**. I followed following steps to configure my deployment.
My database url is-

```
jdbc:sqlserver://spring-sql-server.database.windows.net:1433;database=<database-name>;user=<username>@spring-sql-server;password=<password>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
```

1. Added all my secrets to the GitHub Repository Secrets.
   [image]
2. Added environment variable configuration to my application.properties file.
   [image]

When I build my project using GitHub Actions, I get an error-

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}

I have added the URL properly but still getting this error. (I am not sure, but is it possible that the error might be because of a '#' in my passsword?)

Comment: Did you try changing the password to something that doesn't include a `#` character to see if the error message changes?

Comment: I'd be more curious about why `user=<username>@spring-sql-server;` includes `@spring-sql-server` - is that actually in the SQL Login name on the target server.